# Extending Laravel Validation to Modify Inputs

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to extend the validator in Laravel to validate US phone numbers. My Regex allows for most types (777.777.7777, (777) 777-777, etc), but I want the validator to normalize them. Here is what I've got so far, but it isn't normalizing.

```
Validator::extend('phone', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $value = trim($value);
    if ($value == '') { return true; }
    $match = '/^\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$/';
    $replace = '/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/';
    $return = '($1) $2-$3';
    if (preg_match($match, $value)) 
    {
        return preg_replace($replace, $return, $value);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I figured returning the normalized value might do this, but that doesn't work. How can a validator extension modify the original input?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not to mutate input in the validator and keep it responsible for validating.

However you can achieve what you need using Session:

```
Validator::extend('phone', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $value = trim($value);
    if ($value == '') { return true; }
    $match = '/^\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$/';
    $replace = '/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/';
    $return = '($1) $2-$3';
    if (preg_match($match, $value)) 
    {
        Session::set('mutated', ['phone' => preg_replace($replace, $return, $value)]);
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then simply pull the data from `Session::get('mutated');` array or with dot notation `Session::get('mutated.phone');`.

Comment: This solution is proving difficult to implement. Since I am using updateUniques from Ardent, it is automatically pulling in old input despite the override. I've tried save() and forceSave(), neither of which will work. I'm hoping I can get the Validator to mutate the input.

Comment: Input/Request doesn't offer methods to change obviously, because it's Input :) Better check on Ardent and try to refine their method in some way.